# Can't return empty value to input box on vue

Tags: vue.js, validation

I want made a validation for input to be number only, whenever someone input a string, the input box will be cleared.

First, I made a method function on $event like this (ps. I use props)

```
<BaseInput
      :value="nama"
      @update="nama = ruled($event)"
      label="Nama"
      type="type"
/>
```

and this is the method, I use RegExp to check if the $event value is number. When it's false then I return $event value to empty string.

```
ruled(event) {
  console.log(event)

  var intRegex = new RegExp(/[0-9]/);
  var data = intRegex.test(event)
  if(!data) {
      alert("Value Must Number")
      event = ""
      console.log('masuk if' + data)
  }
  return event
}
```

but it didn't clear the input box, anyone know why it happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestions :**

- Instead of `@update` you have to use `@keypress` or `@change`.
- You can use `v-model` for two-way data binding.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nama: ''
  },
  methods: {
    ruled(event) {
      var intRegex = new RegExp(/^\d+$/);
      var data = intRegex.test(this.nama);
      if (!data) {
        alert("Value must contain number");
        this.nama = "";
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
      v-model="nama"
      @change="ruled($event)"
      label="Nama"
      type="text"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: I use reusable component, and the ruled($event) not running

Comment: you can emit an event on change to original input box component

Comment: like this ?

@change="$emit('update', $event.target.value)" ?

Comment: Yes right and then you can capture this in your parent component.

Comment: I did this on my parent

@update="nama = ruled($event)" 

and the input box still not clearing

Comment: why you are clearing input box on parent component ? Do it in child component only.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue ? If Yes, can you please mark this answer so that it will be useful for other developers as well.

Answer (score 2):

As **Creative Learner** said, I must clearing input box in child component only, so I did this on my component child

```
<template>
<input
  :value="value"
  :placeholder="label"
  @input="$emit('update', ruled($event))"
/>
</template>
```

And this is the methods:

```
    methods: {
      ruled(event) {
        //console.log(event)
            var val = event.target.value
            if(event.target.type == "number"){
                var intRegex = new RegExp(/[0-9]/);
                var intdata = intRegex.test(val)
                    if(intdata == false) {
                        error = "Value must contain number"
                        //alert("Value must contain number")
                        return event.target.value = ""
                    }
            }
      return val
      }
  }
```

great thanks to **Creative Learner** who made me understand